# Antlr V4 C grammar and arrays

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm using ANTLR V4 with the standard C grammar file.  I'm using C#, the basic listener example from the book and attaching to the EnterUnaryExpression event.

But with this input:

```
myArray[1][2] = 10; 
myArray[3][4] = 20; 
myArray[5][6] = 30;
```

Using the EnterUnaryExpression event and outputting `context.GetText()`:

```
EnterUnaryExpression:1

EnterUnaryExpression:2

EnterUnaryExpression:myArray[3][4]

EnterUnaryExpression:3

EnterUnaryExpression:4

EnterUnaryExpression:20

EnterUnaryExpression:myArray[5][6]

EnterUnaryExpression:5

EnterUnaryExpression:6

EnterUnaryExpression:30
```

I don't seem to get the first arrays events i.e in my example where is `myArray[1][2]` and its result 10.  Is this as expected or have I found a problem ?

Comment: Hardly any connection to the C language.

Comment: Sorry got to disagree. Input is C, parsed using the C grammar file.

Comment: Following your argument, you might also add `input`, `file` and `grammar` tags ;-)